# Why secure text entry on button click not working properly

Tags: ios, swift

I’m setting a button to a password textfield with a hide icon. The icon is shown when editing starts in the password. It is given like so...

```
 func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

    for textfield in textFields {
      if textfield.tag == 1 {
        textfield.isValid = true      
      } else {
        textfield.isActive = false
      }
    }
  }
```

When  `textfield.isValid = true`, a `didSet` is called in another class like so..

```
var isValid: Bool = false {
    didSet {
      setCorrectState()
    }
  }
```

The `setCorrectState()` method is given as,

```
 func setCorrectState() {

    if self.type == .password {

      addPasswordViewButton()
    }
  }
```

The `addPasswordViewButton()`method is given as follows…

```
 private func addPasswordViewButton() {

    button.setImage(UIImage(named: "hide"), for: .normal)
    button.setImage(UIImage(named: "show"), for: .selected)
    button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 3)
    button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: ((self.frame.height)), height: ((self.frame.height)))
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(showHidePassword(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    self.rightView = button
    self.rightViewMode = .always
  }
```

`showHidePassword` is given as,

```
  @objc func showHidePassword(_ button: UIButton) {
    button.isSelected = !button.isSelected
    self.isSecureTextEntry = !button.isSelected

  }
```

I’m facing 2 issues here..

1.When I start entering text in the textfield, the hide icon is shown and the text entered is in a secure text format. Now if the hide icon is clicked, the show icon is displayed and the text entered will no more be in the secure-text format. Now in this state itself(where the show icon is displayed), if I delete all characters and click on another textfield(there are more than one textfields apart from this password textfield) and then go back again and click on the passwordtextfield and start entering characters, the show icon itself is shown while I wanted the hide icon and its functionality to be displayed there…

2.Say for instance I entered the characters ‘abc’ in the passwordtextfield. These are now in the secure text format. Now the show icon is displayed and if I click on that, I’ll be able to see the characters ‘abc’ that was entered. Now if I enter ‘def’, I’ll be able to see the characters ‘abcdef’ in total. Now the icon that is shown is hide icon and if I click on that, the text ‘abcdef’ will go in a secure-text format. Now if I enter the character say ‘g’ then instead of ideally accepting ‘g’ as a continuation to ‘abcdef’, ‘g’ gets entered as a new character..i.e..the entire text ‘abcdef’ is wiped out…What could be the reason…?

Comment: Try to avoid tags.

Comment: Basically your password show/hide is not working, right?

Comment: It's working @AbhishekJadhav...but seemingly bit incorrectly...

Comment: @user308123 you can check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Follow this steps:

1 - Create custom **class as PasswordTextField**

```
class PasswordTextField: UITextField {


}
```

2 - Create **outlet of password eye button as passwordButton in PasswordTextField class**

```
@IBOutlet weak var passwordButton: UIButton!
```

3 - Add textField on viewController and add **PasswordTextField class to textField from storyboard**

[image]

4 - Add **IBOutlet connection of passwordButton from storyboard**
[image]

5 - create **one flag handles password show/hide functionality**

```
import UIKit

class PasswordTextField: UITextField {

    @IBOutlet weak var passwordButton: UIButton!

    var isClicked: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            self.isSecureTextEntry = isClicked ? false : true
            isClicked ? (passwordButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "show"), for: .normal)) : (passwordButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "hide"), for: .normal))
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.isSecureTextEntry = true //set default as a isSecureTextEntry
        passwordButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "hide"), for: .normal) // set image to passoword hide eye
        passwordButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(passwordButtonPressed(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside) //create target method of passwordButton
    }

    @objc func passwordButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {

        isClicked = !isClicked

    }
}
```

6 - After this steps, **you don't need to add any code in ViewController, just you want to create PasswordTextField outlet**

```
@IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: PasswordTextField!
```

Comment: This definitely helps you @user308123 Please upvote the answer, if you like my answer